# Are $C^0[a,b]$ and $C^0[0,1]$ isometrically isomorphic?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

Consider $C^0[a,b]$ and $C^0[0,1]$, each equipped with the $L^1$-Norm.
Are these (out of curiosity) isometrically isomorphic?

Comment: Yes, they are. Do you know how an isometry between the two spaces could look if they are endowed with the $L^\infty$-norm? Have you an idea how to change such a bijection to make it isometric for the $L^1$-norms?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. The isomorphism is given by:
$$\begin{array}{llll}
\varphi:&C^0[a,b]&\longrightarrow&C^0[0,1]\\
&f(x)&\longmapsto&(b-a)f(a+(b-a)x)
\end{array}$$

Comment: could you provide a reference for these things?

Comment: @RudidieRennmaus What do you mean exactly by "these things"? If you want references about metric spaces, any book about topology will treat them. If you want functions spaces, then take a look at functional analysis and PDEs.

Comment: no, for this particular fact

Comment: @RudidieRennmaus I didn't use any references. Once you've seen enough similar stuff, it becomes quite intuitive.